# Axios getPosts error: Unexpected token, expected "," (25:4)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an axios getPosts to work. I am getting a syntax error but I can't find what's wrong with my code.

```
getPosts = async () => {
    let data = await api.get('/').then(({ data })
    => data);
    this.setState({ posts: data })
  }
```

The error is posted below:

```
./src/App.js
SyntaxError: /home/roxx/Documents/eternal_kings_web_app/Twitter-Clone/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (25:4)

  23 |   getPosts = async () => {
  24 |     let data = await api.get('/').then(({ data })
> 25 |     => data);
     |     ^
  26 |     this.setState({ posts: data })
  27 |   }
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `async` / `await` with `.then()`? Try `let { data } = await api.get("/")`

Comment: Yes, it does Phil. Thanks, I kept it in one line and it works.

Answer (score -1):

The source of your syntax error is the newline in your arrow function.

Per MDN on [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax): "Multiline statements require body braces and return." To stick with the one-line:

```js
let data = await api.get("/").then(({ data }) => data);
```

And to include the desired `setState`:

```js
let data = await api.get("/").then(({ data }) => this.setState({ posts: data }));
```